# Arithmetic Overflow When Inserting Decimal Value

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have a table scm.agreement_rebate where the column genericrx_percent is of type Decimal(18,4), and when I try to execute this statement

```
INSERT INTO scm.agreement_rebate (agreement_id, rebate_type_cd, genericrx_percent, percent_override,
                                  monthly_fee, monthly_fee_override, percent_amount, sales_type_cd,     
                                  system_generated_flag, last_user_id, last_ts) 
VALUES (43958, 192, 1000.0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1.0, 154, 'N', 1, GETDATE())
```

I get the error

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Procedure TRG_A_R_A_INS_A, Line 11
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.

The problem is definitely with the `generixrx_percent` column. If I change the value to 100.0, it works. As I understand the decimal data type, `Decimal(18, 4)` should give me 18 digits total, with 4 on the right side of the decimal.

What am I missing?

Comment: There's probably some maths going on behind... Check for triggers, (check) constraints, computed columns... I'm quite sure, that it is not the value itself but something you are doing with it...

Comment: Creating a table with a column of Decimal(18,4) and then inserting both 100.0 and 1000.0 works just fine.  Agree with Shnugo, check other stuff going on in your procedure and see how it is working with that value.

Answer (score 0):

Good call, Shnugo.  Turns out that even though I'm the sole developer, there were still some objects in there that I didn't have access to which were doing some funky things.